# Is there a way to keep all the text within a tag the same font color despite single quote usage?

Tags: reactjs, notepad++

I'm doing a course in react and I notice when adding text within a tag and I use a contraction in the sentence (in this case "I'm...") all the text following the single quote is a different color than the preceding "I".  Is there a way to configure notepad++ so it keeps the color of the text the same?  I realize this is purely cosmetic but it would be nice to have consistency of font colors throughout my code.

I've done some searching around but I can't find anything addressing this particular issue.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In the h1 tag the sentence: "Hi, I'm a React App" is where my issue is.  The letters preceding the quote are all one color (so "Hi, I..." are all green in my case) and the letters following are all another due to the way notepad++ is reading the quote and setting colors (so the letters "...'m a React App" are all appearing as white).

Comment: This wont fix notepad++, but you can use <h1>{"Hi, I'm a React App"}</h1> that will also work

Comment: @Gary, did you run the code ? or you're assuming that it will produce text with different color before executing the code ?

Comment: I searched a little and I'm not sure if notepad++ have a plugin for JSX syntax color, but you consider using other text editor, try `sublime text` with `Babel` package